# is there any gitlab API to rename a group

Tags: api, gitlab

I am using GitLab 6.9.2 e46b644, I can not find any API to rename a group from API doc, but from gitlab UI, it really support rename group.

any idea if I need to batch rename groups?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, it's not documented at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4a5044e30269f8b3c6c075093cd4646a478231c7/doc/api/groups.md

Also, it's not implemented at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4a5044e30269f8b3c6c075093cd4646a478231c7/lib/api/groups.rb which would be the obvious place.

And I could not find any feature request at http://feedback.gitlab.com

So I think it is safe to assume that it is not possible. I recommend that you open a feature request at http://feedback.gitlab.com

Comment: Thank u, Ciro, I will open a feature request on this.

Comment: I create it here:http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6778702-gitlab-api-to-rename-a-group

Comment: @Feng: if the answer was useful consider accepting it (green tick under score count). Will give you 2 rep :)